# Storing checkbox values in session and then reselecting them through session

Tags: php, session, checkbox

I am simply trying to pass my checkbox values through a session variable for use if the user goes back at some point. After going to my first page and `POSTING`, I want these selections stored in a `SESSION` variable. I've had no luck so far in figuring this one out. My code is below.

Here is my html of my checkboxes. I have about 15 checkboxes with the same name as below. I take all those checkboxes and break them down in another script for insertion into a database.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='list[]' id='product' value='Product'></input>
```

Here I am setting my variable with the POST of the checkboxes.

```
$checkboxes = $_POST['list'];
$_SESSION['list'] = $checkboxes;
```

How can I pass these checkbox selections into and out of a session variable for selecting elements on a previous page?

Comment: Are you using `session_start()` to start sessions?

Comment: Yeah, I am using session_start().

Comment: On all pages/scripts?

Comment: Yeah, on all pages and scripts.

Comment: I've already tested a few echos back into my form inputs and they work. It's just getting the checkboxes to reselect.

Comment: Oh. So you want to re-select checkboxes based upon your list array directly from $_SESSION?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='list[]' id='product' value='Product'></input>
```

To

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='list[0]' id='product' value='Product'></input>
 <input type='checkbox' name='list[1]' id='product' value='Product'></input>
 etc.
```

And use foreach:

Okay so. We know that in `$_SESSION['list']` we have only checked ones!

```
    foreach ($_SESSION['list'] as $key => $value)
    {

             echo '<input type="checkbox" name="list['$key']" value="'.$value.'" checked="checked >';           
    }
```

Comment: How would I apply that to reselecting checkboxes? Would I wrap that around each input checkbox line?

Comment: For value == blah, would I have to do an if statement for each checkbox that has a different value?

Comment: We know that in `$_SESSION['list']` we have only checked ones! Then we dont need `if(value == blah)`. Just list them all. Updated my post.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you very much for your help rinchik. Awesome solution and explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I share my code / solution for storing the html form checkbox value in a session. My search did not get me to cover all scenarios that I needed.
 
My scenario includes that I pass a default state for checked or not checked.

HTML Form Code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product[]" value = 0>
<input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value = 1 <?php echo (($productvalue == 1) ? 'checked' : '')?>>
```

PHP Form processing code:

```
$productvalue = ((isset($_POST['product'])) ? array_sum((array)$_POST['product']) : ((isset($_SESSION['productsession'])) ? $_SESSION['productsession'] : 0));
$_SESSION['productsession'] = $productvalue;
```